# How to get Width/Height of Button in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i Get Height/Width of Any View (Button , TextView , RelativeLayout) in fragment, i try something like that

```
 public static class FirstDemoFragment extends Fragment {

    int width,height;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_demo_button);

        width =  button.getWidth();
        height = button.getHeight();


        System.out.println("==== View Width : " + width);
        System.out.println("==== View height : " + height);

        width = button.getMeasuredWidth();
        height = button.getMeasuredHeight();


        System.out.println("==== View Width : " + width);
        System.out.println("==== View height : " + height);

        return view;
    }
```

my layout.xml file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/does_really_work_with_fragments"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_demo_button"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

i have a little research on that, I have found Width/Height of Button in Activity using this method.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    relMain = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutMain);

    width = relMain.getMeasuredWidth();
    height = relMain.getMeasuredHeight();

    width = relMain.getWidth();
    height = relMain.getHeight();

    //System.out.println("=== Width : " + width);
    //System.out.println("=== height : " + height);


}
```

but onWindowFocusChanged() is not available in android Fragment ?

Comment: Is application crashing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Fragment try below code in Fragment's onCreateView method:

```
button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_demo_button);   
     ViewTreeObserver vto = button.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                button.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                Log.d("", "Height: " + button.getMeasuredHeight()+ " Width: " + button.getMeasuredWidth());
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Gaurav Mandlik please vote the answer if it helped you.

Comment: It helped me in achieving desired output. Thanks bro

Answer (score 2):

In Fragment use below code in Fragment's `onCreateView` method

```
ViewTreeObserver mviewtreeobs = button.getViewTreeObserver();
mviewtreeobs .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
    width = button.getWidth();
    height = button.getHeight(); 
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a layout listener to your button like so:

```
button.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int width = button.getWidth();
            if(width > 0){
              int height = button.getHeight();
              // do something with your width and height
              ....
              // remove layout listener
              button.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); 
            }
        }
```